# Print text when changing color of path onclick

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to make a game where you need to click the circles. Each circle changes color when you click on it. I want it to say "congrats" when all circles have been clicked but at the moment it shows 'congrats' just after one circle has been pressed. Any idea how I could fix this?

```
var text = new PointText(view.center);
text.content = 'Congrats';
text.visible = false;
text.style = {
    fontFamily: 'Courier New',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 100,
    fillColor: 'black',
    justification: 'center'
}

for (l = 0; l < balls.length; l++) {
    balls[l].onClick = function(event) {
        counter++



    this.fillColor = '#860d2b';
    var areAnyCoral = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < balls.length; j++) {
        if (balls[j].fillColor === 'coral') {
            areAnyCoral = true;
        }
    };
    if (areAnyCoral === false) {
        text.visible = true;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What you have here looks fine as far as I can see. Where is the set up for the balls variable? Specifically, how are they assigned the fillColor?

Comment: Here is the whole code http://goo.gl/MBN5jB

Comment: looks ot me like when you create the balls, all have fillColor equal to `coral`, so when one is clicked, your balls[j].fillColor === 'coral' is always true.

Comment: any idea how to fix this?

Comment: the aim of the game is to click each ball. When you click it it becomes purple. The game is finished when all balls are purple.

Comment: ah, right. See Shaun's answer, I think he has it right. Though you could also check for the new color, not "coral" if you wanted to.

Comment: I think part of your issue is what fillColor represents. If you print out console.log(this.fillColor) you can see that it is an object, not a string like "coral". Which is why your comparison is always false. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be checking against the `counter`, rather than the fill color, for the `text.visible` property. Does this make sense?

```
var counter = 0;
var ball1 = {
  color: "notCoral"
};

var ball2 = {
  color: "notCoral"
}

var balls = [ball1, ball2];

balls.forEach(function(ball) {
  ball.onClick = function(event) {
    if (ball.color == "notCoral") {
      ball.color = "coral";
      counter++;
    }

    if (counter == balls.length) {
      text.visible = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense, not 100 % sure I'll be able to implement it but I do think this is should work!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to change:

```
balls[j].fillColor === 'coral';
```

to:

```
balls[j].fillColor.equals('coral');
```

because fillColor is an object, you need to use the "equals" method to compare a string color like that: http://paperjs.org/reference/color/#equals-color